# Syfmony 4: Check if user has a "remember me" cookie

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have read through this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-opt-out-of-the-remember-me-feature) and can see how one can use `isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')` to determine if the user is logged in via any means, and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` to determine if the user logged in that session. Is there a standard way to determine if the user specifically used a "remember me" cookie?

From the docs:

> IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED: All logged in users have this, even if
>   they are logged in because of a "remember me cookie". Even if you
>   don't use the remember me functionality, you can use this to check if
>   the user is logged in.

So how can you tell if the user did use the remember me cookie for auth?

For example:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{

  $user = $token->getUser();
  if($user->hasRememberMeToken?) {
    //bypass multi-factor authentication
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case with the listener the easiest way is probably to inspect the type of token you got:

```php
if ($token instanceof RememberMeToken) {
    ...
}
```

Symfony uses different token types, so by default you should be relatively safe that this token was obtained via the remember me-functionality. If you have custom logic it might not be as easy though.

There is no short hand for this, but you could make sure the roles on the user match the requirements of being not fully authenticated, but authenticated via remember me using the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker` like this:

```php
if ($checker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') === true
    && $checker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === false
) {
    ...
}
```